# Android getting text from a URL always NULL

Tags: android, http-request

I'd like to send an http request and get a string back from that request.

I am currently using this code, but no matter what my URL is, I always get null. What's the issue?

> try {
>       // Create a URL for the desired page
>       URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/index.html");
>
> ```
> // Read all the text returned by the server
> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
> String str;
> while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
>     // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
> }
> in.close(); } catch (MalformedURLException e) { } catch (IOException e) { }
> ```

Comment: The code is working fine, if you supply a proper url.
As you're trying to do this on Android, have you set the proper Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I have added the internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. I do give it proper URL but get null every time.

Comment: As a matter of fact, my URL was incorrect, now I have corrected it and I get an exception "java.io.EOFException". This is of course tested with my original code.

Comment: The url is this => http://tinyurl.com/coajz9p  The string that will need to be back from that particular URL is: YldZbUZNakF3TUE9PQ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                String URL = "http://hostname:80/index.html"
                String XML = stringWriter.toString();
                // System.out.println(XML);

                se = new StringEntity(XML, "UTF-8");
                se.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(se);

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

try use from this code

Comment: As a matter of fact, my URL was incorrect, now I have corrected it and I get an exception "java.io.EOFException". This is of course tested with my original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
URL url = new URL("http://whatever");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
//read stream here
```

Comment: I tested the above and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        String url = "Your URL";
        try{
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){ //Don't know what string you are waiting for
                 //do something
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            httpClient.close();
        }
```

Comment: I get an error on this line: "HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);".

Comment: These are a few first lines of the errors: // Field descriptor #9 Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;
  protected final org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager connManager;
  
  // Field descriptor #11 Lorg/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoutePlanner;
  protected final org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoutePlanner routePlanner;
  
  // Field descriptor #13 Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionReuseStrategy;
  protected final org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy reuseStrategy;